# Laravel Sentry catching errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am using Sentry and 'catch' to catch errors:

```
    catch (UserExistsException $e)
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('error',$e->getMessage());
    }
```

My redirect does not work though, it goes to the Laravel error screen with the right error message error "Cartalyst \ Sentry \ Users \ UserExistsException A user already exists with login [email@email.com], logins must be unique for users." with REDIRECT_STATUS   200.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've been there too…
Catching this exception will work when you use the right namespace, watch out for the starting slash:

catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserExistsException $e){ //do your thing; }

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I see that exceptions now are really there as a last resort, I'll deal with it better in validation and catch it there.